# How do I hotwire a vehicle faster?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm playing Grand Theft Auto V on Xbox One currently. In Grand Theft Auto IV, if you flicked the left and right triggers very fast while Niko was hotwiring a vehicle, it would complete faster. Is this also a functionality in Grand Theft Auto V? From experimentation, it seems to work on a few vehicles, but I'm not 100% sure. Anyone know if this was implemented?

Answer (score 2):

Although I couldn't find any official info, I can tell from my experience that this feature does not work anymore. The developers should have implemented this feature in GTA V as well...